# Sending an email to AOL is being delayed and emails becomes undeliverable

Tags: email, domain, hotmail, aol

While trying to send an email from my work's domain I receive a bounce back in about 4hrs so the email does not reach the targeted person. I have send an email from Hotmail account to the same AOL address just to receive another bounce back. I have also tried sending an email from Gmail to AOL which resulted in no bounce back but the AOL user did not receive the email. I can receive an email from AOL. Is anybody else having similar problem? What would be the best course of action to resolve this? Thanks

Edit:

The following is the bounce back on the hotmail account.

> < #5.1.1 smtp;550 5.1.1
>   : Recipient address
>   rejected: aol.com> #SMTP#

Edit 2:

What I have got from Mailserver is an error #4.4.7 which according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284204):

> typically indicates an issue on the
>   receiving server. Verify the validity
>   of the recipient address, and verify
>   that the receiving server is
>   configured to receive messages
>   correctly

Comment: Has AOL finally shut down? No, seriously though: What does the bounce say specifically? In most cases it reveals the real problem.

Comment: Yes please post the bounce back here for us (make sure you take out the email address). You can parse the headers with this http://www.mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx

Comment: Oh, yes, I wish people moved away from AOL because it is causing me a lot of headache trying to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Take a look at AOL's [postmaster site](http://postmaster.aol.com/) you may be able to get in contact with them.  Not sure otherwise.

Comment: All I can find on the web is cases from 2010 which were due to some servers being knocked out and some other crap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding RDNS to one of my IPs solved the problem for emails send from my domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a trouble ticket to AOL [here](http://postmaster.aol.com/SupportRequest.php).

> If you are an email service provider, an email administrator, or a non-AOL entity having trouble sending email to AOL Members please select the most appropriate option below.

Comment: Well, it would be great to do that but I am seeing this problem at my work's domain, hotmail, and gmail

Comment: Your question states you are having trouble sending to AOL only. Are you getting similar errors when sending to your work domain, gmail, hotmail etc.?  The message basically means the mailbox you're trying to send to doesn't exist.  But I'd have to assume you've already confirmed it works and that you've spelt it right, so you'll have to ask AOL why it's not getting there.

Comment: I am having problems while trying to send an email to AOL from work domain, gmail, and hotmail

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be the classic phone call. Although I've heard it isn't too good calling AOL, it seems their mail just isn't up.

Comment: I could do that but in order to get a phone number I need an AOL account.